# In VueJS component, how to use Table with Data Rows from Subcomponent

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vue-component

I am having trouble displaying data headers and rows together when the data is coming from a separate subcomponent. The headers and the data display, but the headers do not align (or even overlap) with the data which displays below them.

Here is the main component:

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <NewBook  v-on:book-created="getOwnedBooks(user.id)" />
    <h6 class="text-muted mt-3">Books You Are Offering:</h6> 
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Authors</th>
          <th>Date added</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(book, i) in books" :key="`${i}-${book.id} `">
          <UserBook :book="book" v-on:book-deleted="getOwnedBooks"/>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserBook from "@/components/Books/UserBook";
import NewBook from "@/components/Books/NewBook";

export default {
  name: "UserBooks",
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    UserBook,
    NewBook
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getOwnedBooks();
  },
  computed: {
    books() {
      return this.$store.state.ownedBooks;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getOwnedBooks () {
      console.log('In UserBooks.vue, getting owned books')
      console.log('In UserBooks.vue, this.user is: ', this.user)
      this.$store.dispatch("getOwnedBooks", this.user);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the subcomponent that presents each row of the table data:

```
<template>
<div>
  <td>
    <router-link :to="`/books/${book.id}`" class="lightbox">
      {{ book.title }}
    </router-link>
  </td>
  <td>{{ book.authors[0] }}</td>
  <td>{{ moment(book.created_at).strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") }}</td>
  <td>
    <div flat color="grey" @click="deleteBook(book.id)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash " ></i>
    </div>
  </td>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import BooksService from '../../services/BooksService'
import LoansService from '../../services/LoansService'
import moment from 'moment-strftime';
export default {
  name: "UserBook",
  props: {
    book: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    me() {
      return this.$store.getters.user
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteBook: async function (id) {
      if(confirm("Do you really want to remove this book from your collection?")) {
        let response = await BooksService.deleteBook(id)
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('In Book.vue, book deleted, about to emit');
          this.$emit('book-deleted');
        }
      }
    },
    async borrowBook(id) {
      console.log('in Book.vue starting book request for book with id: ', id)
      let response = await LoansService.addLoan({
        borrowerId: this.me.id,
        bookId: id,
        lenderId: this.book.users_id // we already have the book. is this nec?
      }) 
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log('In Book.vue, loan has been requested, about to emit');
        this.$emit('loan-requested');
        this.displayNotice();
      }
    },
    bookOwner(book) {
      return this.me.id == book.users_id
    },
    displayNotice() {
      let phrase = "You have requested to borrow this book. The book owner will be notified."
      let title = "Book Loan Requested"
      this.$snotify.success(phrase, title,{
        timeout: 3500,
        showProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: false,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        position: "centerTop"
      })
    },
    moment: function (datetime) {
      return moment(datetime);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course they don't align. The problem is that you create tr tag with div inside instead of separate tds. That is not a valid way of building HTML tables. I suggest changing architecture that would wrap it into a single Table component or use [enter link description here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components), which enables you to create the template without wrapping div. I recommend first approach since functional components have to be stateless and instanceless (just for showing data) and that would result in additional refactoring.

Comment: fair enough. took your advice and stopped trying to abstract the table data. Thanks for your help.